# How to handle multiple NavHosts/NavControllers?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-architecture

I'm having a problem when dealing with multiple NavHosts. This issue is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637482/how-to-use-navcontroller-with-a-navhost-in-a-fragment-in-a-fragment-rather-tha). I think the solution for this question would help me as well, but it's a post from 2017 and it still has no answer. Android Developers Documentation doesn't help and searching through the web shows absolutely nothing that could possibly help.

So basically I have one Activity and two Fragments. Let's call them
FruitsActivity, FruitListFragment, FruitDetailFragment, where FruitsActivity has no relevant code and its xml layout is composed by a `<fragment>` tag, serving as `NavHost`, like that:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/fruits_nav_graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The FruitListFragment is the startDestination of my NavGraph, it handles a list of fruits that will come from the server.
The FruitDetailFragment shows details about the Fruit selected in the list displayed by FruitListFragment.

So far we have Activity -> ListFragment -> DetailFragment.

Now I need to add one more Fragment, called GalleryFragment. It's a simple fragment that displays many pictures of the Fruit selected and it's called by FruitDetailFragment when clicking a button.

The problem here is: In Portrait mode I simply use `findNavController().navigate(...)` and I navigate through the Fragments like I want. but when I'm using a Tablet in Landscape mode, I'm using that Master Detail Flow to display List and Details on the same screen. There is an example of how it works [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial), and I want the GalleryFragment to replace the FruitDetailFragment, sharing the screen with the list of fruits, but so far I could only manage to make it replace the "main navigation" flow, occupying the entire screen and sending the FruitListFragment to the Back Stack.

I already tried to play around with `findNavController()` method, but no matter from where I call it I can only get the same `NavController` all the time, and it always navigates in the same linear way.
I tried to implement my own NavHost, but I get and error "class file for androidx.navigation.NavHost not found".

This is the xml of my FruitsActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/listing_nav_graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

This is the xml of the FruitListActivity in Landscape mode (in portrait mode there is just the RecyclerView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvFruits"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/sideFragmentContainer"
                    android:name="fruits.example.FruitDetailFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

And now I want to call the GalleryFragment and make it replace just the `<fragment>` of id 'sideFragmentContainer' instead of the whole screen (instead of replacing the `<fragment>` of id `fragmentContainer` in the Activity's xml).

I didn't find any explanations of how to handle multiple NavHosts or `<fragment>` inside `<fragment>`.

So based on that, is it possible to use Navigation Architecture and display a Fragment inside another Fragment? Do I need multiple NavHosts for that, or is there another way?

Comment: I actually seen something similar to this in a blog post about using navhosts in different layouts for tablet and phone. See blog post [here](https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974). It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but is close, I'll have a chance later on today to test a few things out (currently in work atm)

Comment: @jsmyth886 Indeed, it gets close to what I want to achieve. I'll check it out asap. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by [jsmyth886](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353832/jsmyth886), [this blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974) pointed me to the right direction.
    The trick was to `findFragmentById()` to get the `NavHost` directly from the fragment container (in this case, the one sharing the screen with the rest of the Master Detail screen). This allowed me to access the correct `NavController` and navigate as expected.
    It's important to create a second `NavGraph` too.

So a quick step-by-step:

- Create the main `NavGraph` to make all the usual navigation (how it would work without the Master Detail Flow);
- Create a secondary `NavGraph` containing only the possible `Destinations` that the Master Detail fragment will access. No `Actions` connecting then, just the `Destinations`.
- In the main `<fragment>` container, set the attributes like that:

```
    <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

- The `app:defaultNavHost="true"` is important. Then the Master Detail layout will look like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvFruits"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <fragment
                            android:id="@+id/sideFragmentContainer"
                            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                            app:navGraph="@navigation/secondary_nav_graph"
                            app:defaultNavHost="false"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </layout>
```

- Again, the attribute `app:defaultNavGraph` is important, set it to false here.
- In the code part, you should have a boolean flag to verify if your app is running on a Tablet or not (the link provided in the beginning of the answer explains how to do it). In my case, I have it as a `MutableLiveData` inside my `ViewModel`, like that I can observe it and change layouts accordingly.
- If is not tablet (i.e. follows the normal navigation flow), simply call `findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_action_id_from_detail_to_some_other_fragment)`. The main navigation will happen using the main `NavController`;
- If is tablet using the Master Detail Flow, you must find the correct `NavHost` and `NavController` by finding the `<fragment>` that contains it, like that:

```
val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id. sideFragmentContainer) as NavHostFragment
```

- And finally you can navigate to the Fragment that you want to appear dividing the screen with the rest of the Master Detail screen by calling `navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.id_of_the_destination)`. Notice that here we don't call `Actions`, we call the `Destination` directly.

That's it, simpler than what I thought. Thank you Lara Martín for the blog post and jsmyth886 for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Nice one, glad to have helped :)

Comment: @Rver I have a similar issue with my project and I would like to know if you have a Github repo to check your code?