# Master-Detail views with Navigation Components

Tags: kotlin, tablet, landscape, android-architecture-navigation, android-viewbinding

I'm using Navigation Component with a navGraph. I have one `activity` with a `NavHost` and I would like to have in tablet landscape mode one `activity` with 2 `fragments`. I have already read [this](https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974) but I'm using `viewBinding` and I cannot understand how I can implement this to have the same result. I found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804449/how-to-handle-multiple-navhosts-navcontrollers) but
the question was asked 1,5 year ago so maybe it's something new to implement that properly.

My `MainActivity` :

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

My `ListFragment` :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EFEDED"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.ListFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_property" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my `ListFragment` tablet land :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EFEDED"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.ListFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/nav_host_fragment_tablet"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_property" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_tablet"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:defaultNavHost="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/rv_list"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_tablet" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```